# How to change an element if a form was autofilled?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, autofill

I need to change the position of one element if a form was auto-filled.
I tried to do that via CSS.

```js
$('html').on('input', function() {
    console.log("Click");
});
$("input").on("change keyup blur input", function(e) {
    console.log("HelloWorld");
});
```

```css
input:-webkit-autofill~div,
input:-webkit-autofill:hover~div,
input:-webkit-autofill:focus~div,
form:-webkit-autofill~div,
form:-webkit-autofill:hover~div,
form:-webkit-autofill:focus~div,
{
  left: 100px;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
<form>
  <label>
    <input name="username">
  </label>
</form>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

My console log is empty.
But it works if I click the input.

Screenshots:

[image: Page load: (gray text is not a placeholder. It's a div).]

Page load: (gray text is not a placeholder. It's a div).

[image: After click the input]

After click the input

*upd: seems, I've found a solution.
On the link: https://medium.com/weekly-webtips/detecting-chrome-autofill-on-page-load-78ea178e4a68 the author use timeout for the checking. But I think it is not a good solution. Any other ways? I understand why my script doesn't work:
Html -> css -> js -> and then after user scripts run a browser set autofill. But I can't understand why `on change` doesn't work.

*upd: timeout also doesn't work:

```js
async function asyncRunner(callback, args, timeout) {
    setTimeout(callback, timeout, args)
}
var test = void (bool isInitialised) {
    foreach (var index in $(".form-field input"))
    {
        if ($(index).is("input"))
        {
            if (isInitialised == false && index.value != "")
            {
                $(index).parent().parent().addClass("focus");
                Console.log("Autofilled");
            }
            else
            {
                Console.log(index.value);
                Console.log(isInitialised);
                Console.log("Notautofilled");
            }
        }
    }
};

$(function() {
    InputEvent inpenv = new InputEvent();
    asyncRunner(test, inpenv.isInitialised, 3000).then(Console.log("Done")); // 27
};
```

It's js++ code but native javascript code has the same problem;
In the log values are marked as `""`

Comment: `.bind()` is ages long deprecated in favor of the `.on()` Method

Comment: Closing this one as a typo. Always make sure you included your `<script>` tags right **before** the closing `</body>` tag.

Comment: @Roko C. Buljan, `on` also doesn't work. In script I use `$(function() {});` and script I placed to bottom of the body tag. Doesn't 'work. But it works if I click the input;

Comment: [That answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54631539/when-i-autocomplete-input-field-value-is-overrides-by-the-label-and-not-getting) solves my problem.